# Combine multiple greps with regex

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have this file:

```
10 replies
Big Horse
123sdf562
replies
1354654
Fat Cat
2 replies
White Horse
Big Cat
Little Dog
5 replies
725vgfvjgh123
Black Horse
Brown Cow
8798jgjh
```

I want to extract lines that content the word horse, the word replies preceding by a number and letters enclosed by numbers. So my desired output must be:

```
10 replies
Big Horse
123sdf562
2 replies
White Horse
5 replies
725vgfvjgh123
Black Horse
```

This code `grep '[0-9] replies\|[0-9][a-z]\|Horse' file` returns

```
Big Horse
123sdf562
2 replies
White Horse
5 replies
725vgfvjgh123
Black Horse
8798jgjh
```

but `8798jgjh` should not be in the output because `jgjh` is not enclosed by numbers.

`grep '[0-9] replies\|[0-9][a-z][0-9]\|Horse' file` doesn't work. So, How can achive the right output?

Comment: It could be any tool that do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this with GNU `grep`:

```bsh
$ grep 'Horse\|^[0-9]\+ replies$\|^[0-9]\+[^0-9]\+[0-9]\+$' file
10 replies
Big Horse
123sdf562
2 replies
White Horse
5 replies
725vgfvjgh123
Black Horse
```

---

The problem with your command is that you are not quantifying the `[a-z]`, so it looks for just one character.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this `grep`. The idea with `\{1,\}` quantifier (in BRE) used in multiple places is to match at-least one character of the group used along. A portable version would be to do

```
grep '[0-9]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}replies\|Horse\|[0-9]\{1,\}[a-z]\{1,\}[0-9]\{1,\}' file
```

On `grep` versions that support ERE, e.g. GNU grep, the additional escape characters on the expressions are not needed

```
grep -E '[0-9]{1,}[[:space:]]+replies|Horse|[0-9]{1,}[a-z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}' file
```

You could replace the character class groups `[0-9]`, `[a-z]` with locale independent groups like `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:lower:]]` also.

<sup>[Regular expression - review](https://regex101.com/r/ABrzB9/1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using standard `grep`, you would provide the utility with the separate expressions that you would want to match the lines against.

```bsh
grep \
    -e 'Horse' \
    -e '[[:digit:]]\{1,\} replies' \
    -e '[[:digit:]]\{1,\}[[:alpha:]]\{1,\}[[:digit:]]\{1,\}' file
```

The `\{n,m\}` forces the previous expression to match at least `n` times, and at most `m` times.  This means `\{1,\}` makes the previous expression match at least once, just like `+` would do in a POSIX extended regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne '.put if .grep( m:i/ horse / | / <digit>+ <ws> replies / | / <digit>+ <alpha>+ <digit>+ / );'
```

Sample Input:

```
10 replies
Big Horse
123sdf562
replies
1354654
Fat Cat
2 replies
White Horse
Big Cat
Little Dog
5 replies
725vgfvjgh123
Black Horse
Brown Cow
8798jgjh
```

Sample Output:

```
10 replies
Big Horse
123sdf562
2 replies
White Horse
5 replies
725vgfvjgh123
Black Horse
```

Here's a solution using Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. The Raku (a.k.a. Perl6) effort started in year 2000, and includes a major revision to PCRE (Regular Expressions), which some people find more readable.

The code above uses Raku's `grep` command, which can take multiple `m/…/` Regex matchers, in this case connected by a `|` Boolean OR. Note the first matcher will allow case-insensitive matching of `horse` because it uses the `:i` case-insensitive "adverb". If you only want `Horse` to match, then change accordingly (and delete the `:i` adverb).

Of course it pays to be cautious when writing out Regexes, and you should note that not only will `m/ Horse /` match `Big Horse`, `Black Horse`, and `White Horse`, but `Horse-faced` as well. You may only want lines containing `Horse` when preceded by another word with intervening whitespace, in which case `m/ <alpha>+ <ws> Horse /` may fit the bill.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org